# The official template for journal Briefings of Bioinformatics has error during compilation

Tags: templates, authoryear-icomp

I am recently preparing a manuscript to be submitted to Briefings of Bioinformatics. The journal suggests using the universal OUP latex template to format the manuscript.

The default setting of the template follows author-year style although the journal requires the Vancouver reference style.

First, I downloaded the .bst file for Vancouver style from CTAN and specified it via `\bibliographystyle{vancouver}`. However, the following error message showed up during compiling:

`Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers).`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Note that this is a Question-Answer site, so your post does not fully fit the format. It would be better if you split your post in two, and move the part from "After several attempts" to the Answer box. Furthermore it would be useful to specify where you got the OUP style from, and a small but complete example document that produced the error. This would allow future visitors to confirm quickly if they are dealing with the same problem or not.

Comment: If the journal suggests a template that conflicts with their requirements, I would think that the first step would be to tell the journal and let them figure things out.

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts, the error has been resolved by replacing the following line in the original oup-authoring-template.cls file:

`\RequirePackage{natbib}`

with

`\RequirePackage[square, comma, sort, numbers]{natbib}`.